# Going through array using for_each loop in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays

First off, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;




class Array
{

    int* arr;
    int n;

    public:

    Array();
    Array(const Array&);
    Array(Array &&);
    Array& operator=(const Array&);
    Array& operator=(Array &&);
    void print();
    ~Array();
};

Array::Array()
{
    cout<<"No of elements: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    if(n!=0)
    {
       arr = new int [n];
       cout<<"\nInsert values:"<<endl;
       for_each(arr, arr+n, [](int x){cin>>x;});
    }
}

Array::Array (const Array& a)
{   
    int i=0;
    this->n=a.n;
    arr= new int [n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       arr[i]=a.arr[i];
}

Array::Array (Array &&a)
{
    this->n=a.n;
    arr=a.arr;
    a.arr=nullptr;
}

Array& Array::operator=(const Array& a)
{
    int i=0;
    this->n=a.n;
    arr= new int [n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       arr[i]=a.arr[i];
    return *this;
}

Array& Array::operator=(Array &&a)
{
    this->n=a.n;
    arr=a.arr;
    a.arr=nullptr;
    return *this;
}

void Array::print()
{
    for_each(arr, arr+n, [](int a){cout<<a;});
}

Array::~Array()
{
    n=0;
    delete [] arr;
}

int main()
{   
    Array a;
    Array b;
    Array c=a;
    Array d;
    d=b;
    c.print();
    cout<<endl;
    d.print();

    return 0;
}
```

So, as you can see, i made default constructor (if constructor with no parameters can be called default) that creates an array using for_each loop with lambda function used as a third parameter, all it does, as you can see is that it accepts the values i insert and places it as a values of variable x, which should take values from arr[0] to arr[n-1].

However, when i print put any of arrays created in main, it prints out only zeroes, it is not due to copy constructors, because i tried printing arrays a and b and same thing happened (notice that in this case i am printing out c and d, as they are copies of a and b, respectively).

I also tried to see if it works properly as i tried to print out some elements  of array right after for_each loop finished, and it turns out that for_each loop has no effect on the array as it stays zero even right after loop.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: A non-template constructor with no parameters is *the* default constructor, so you can definitely call it that, but constructors should not interact with the user.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Post this to codereview.stackexchange.com. Apart from the issue you're having, there are a bunch of things to fix and/or improve. Consider for example using zero, a negative number or nothing at all as input for the size in the constructor. Think about what it causes there and also what it causes to happen inside the destructor.

Comment: You may want to look at [std::istream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), [std::ostream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) and [std::copy_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're using `for_each` loops, you're passing a lambda,

```cpp
for_each(arr, arr+n, [](int x){cin>>x;});
```

But the argument of the lambda `(int x)`, mean that you're creating a copy of an array element, that you will assign a value to. That copy will be destroyed when you leave the body of the lambda, while the original value inside the array remains unchanged.

Change it to

```cpp
for_each(arr, arr+n, [](int& x){cin>>x;});
```

That way you won't create a copy of the value inside the array, but you'll pass a reference to it, which means you will write the values into the array.